# Any way to Implement Excel LINEST function using boost libraries?

Tags: c++, excel, math, boost

Does boost::math have any functions that could be used to help to implement a function that is similar to MS Excel LINEST function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I parsed the Boost documentation (not in boost::math, it looks more like boost::ublas). For now, I couldn't find an example simple enough not to be overkill for a non-mathematician.

From what I saw, I would rather advise using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), as its use seems fairly straightforward.

I have reproduced below a simplified code example taken from the [armadillo source archive](http://armadillo.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.9.2/example__lsq_8cpp-source.html):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // points to which we will fit the line
  mat data = "1 6; 2 5; 3 7; 4 10";

  // Transform the problem into an Armadillo use-case (Ax = b problem)
  vec b(data.n_rows);
  mat C(data.n_rows, 2);
  for(u32 i=0; i<data.n_rows; ++i)
  {
    b(i)   = data(i,1);
    C(i,0) = 1;
    C(i,1) = data(i,0);
  }

  // Compute least-squares solution, should be "3.5; 1.4"
  vec solution = solve(C,b);
  cout << "solution:" << endl << solution << endl;

  return 0;
}
```